# Ruby on Rails routes trouble for deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I tried running this program in Sinatra, but Heroku wouldn't let me work with it.  It deployed successfully but it would not run in Heroku so I decided to start this program in rails.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#index'
  # get 'cookies#index'
  # get 'cakes#index'
  # get 'cookies#index'
  # get 'crumbcakes#index'
  # get 'cupcakes#index'
  # get 'events#index'
  # get 'muffins#index'
  # get 'pastries#index'

  resources :index
  # resources :about
  # resources :cakes
  # resources :cookies
  # resources :crumbcakes
  # resources :cupcakes
  # resources :events
  # resources :muffins
  # resources :pastries
end
```

I have this as the routes in Rails, but I commented them out because it would only work on the index page.  I have index on the controllers and views for each one.  Only an index.  I do not know if I did not put the routes in the correct format.  Let me know if you could help me thanks!

Comment: This question does not make sense - you do realize that sinatra is a completely different framework?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have routes for only index action for various controllers you need to specify as below:

```
resources :controller_name, only: %i(index)
  or
resources :controller_name, only: [:index]
```

Comment: The controller would be muffins_controlller.rb

Comment: then you need to specify like   resources :muffins, only: %i(index)

Comment: its `resources :resource_name(plural)`. The controller name is inferred.

Answer (score 0):

It would be

```
resources :cookies, only: [:index]
resources :cakes, only: [:index]
resources :muffins, only: [:index]
 .....
```

Check out the official guide for clear concept [guides.rubyonrails.org/routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting)